# Getting socket timeout exception with multiple simultaneous network calls

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I have a requirement to make multiple api calls parallel in my screen. I noticed a strange issue with this. When I get socket timeout exception for one api call, the other parallel calls also getting the same exception. If I test the other calls, they are working fine. Not sure what is the exact issue. Here is my code.

```
// getting ok http client
private static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        // Remove cookies from the request
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        cookieManager.getCookieStore().removeAll();

        try {
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

            OkHttpClient client;
                client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())
                        .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                        .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
                        .connectTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // set the request timeout
                        .readTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .hostnameVerifier((hostname, session) -> true)
                        .build();

            client.dispatcher().setMaxRequestsPerHost(20);
            client.dispatcher().setMaxRequests(20);
            return client;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

// making api call

public static void makeNetworkRequest(Call<JSONObject> requestCall, final NetworkListener networkListener){

        // define the request callback object
        Callback<JSONObject> requestCallback = new Callback<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {
                networkListener.onSuccess(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                networkListener.onFailure(CONN_FAILED);
            }
        };

        // make the request
        requestCall.enqueue(requestCallback);
    }
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Are all of the calls trying to connect with the same backend?

Comment: Try to increase the value of REQUEST_TIMEOUT.

Comment: @Anubis - Yes. I have identified the problem, I defined the Retrofit client object as singleton. If I create the instance for every call, its working fine. Is there any limit for no.of instances of Retrofit?

Comment: @KaushikBurkule - Tried that also. But still not working. I have identified the problem, I defined the Retrofit client object as singleton. If I create the instance for every call, its working fine. Is there any limit for no.of instances of Retrofit?

Comment: There is no need for adding retrofit in the singleton class to access from multiple activities. Just make a single class and call it anytime, anywhere you want.

Comment: Assuming that all calls call the same API and that they are all executed in parallel, it then seems only normal for the calls to all time out simultaneously since the API is not responding in time. I would suggest examining your API.

Comment: @Anubis - From the logcat, I can see that api calls are different and only one api call is having problem and all are initiated in parallel.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have identified the problem, I defined the Retrofit client object as singleton. If I create the instance for every call, its working fine.

Comment: This is neither a good solution, nor the right way to use Retrofit. Creating a new Retrofit instance for every call is very resource intensive and produces a lot of overhead.

Comment: @Anubis Thanks for the comment. Could you please let me know how to resolve the issue?

Comment: @Anubis I have one more point. Though, we create the retrofit instance for every call, after getting the response, I believe its taken care as part of GC and the memory allocation will be cleared. Hence not keeping it as singleton. Please suggest.